# Display div data in other div with jquery when all divs with same classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not familiar with jQuery, so I am writing this to get some help from you guys.

Let's say that I have three `<div>`s with the same classes, but with different information. On refresh, the page displays only one `<div>` with data in it.

I've made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3deG/) demo.

**Script**

```
var divs = $("div.visible-content").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,1)
$(divs).show();
```

**My question**

How do I display visible data in another, custom `<div>` in another class, which (sorry for my bad English), is not the same as "***.visible-content***" ? I mean, that only IF .visible-content is visible, then information from that visible `<div>` should be displayed in the custom `<div>` with the `.information-from-visible-content` class.

**My full HTML**

```
<div class="visible-content">
   <div class="information">1</div>
</div>

<div class="visible-content">
   <div class="information">2</div>
</div>

<!-- .etc -->
```

```
<div class="other-content">
   <h1>Other content</h1>
   <div class="information-from-visible-content">
   <!-- information from visible content-->
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.visible-content { position:absolute; display:none; }
.other-content { float:left; margin:0px 0px; width:100px; height:100px; background:red; }
.other-content h1 { float:left; margin:0px 0px; font-size:12px; }
```

Sorry for my bad English, and thanks for all the answers!

Comment: So you only want to show the information if the div is visible?

Comment: are you saying that  if either one of the class `.visible-content` is visible, then display the info from the '.visible-content .information'  into  `.other-content .information-from-visible-content`?

Comment: Yes, i am saying, that if .visible-content is visible, than .information should be displayed in `.information-from-visible-content` . I dont know how to say properly in english, but information should be displayed only from that `visible-content` div, not from all divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure if I get the correct meaning from your question, try this if this is what you want

this code will assign the info from .visible-content that is not hidden

```
$('.other-content .information-from-visible-content').text($('.visible-content:not(:hidden) .information').text())
```

check this fiddle, i had update it, http://jsfiddle.net/b3deG/2/

check this fiddle for hide white area info, http://jsfiddle.net/b3deG/10/

Comment: Hmm, thats strange. If i am using your code, than information is not displayed from `.visible-content`. If i am writing information by hand in `.information-from-visible-content`, than information is also not displaying.

Comment: Ok, my bad, i check your css, your css actually hide everything that is `.visible-content`, so thats why the value is always empty, so when it actually will visible?

Comment: Ok, I saw your fiddle, I use your sample fiddle, and the value is display in the other-content, is this the thing you want?

Comment: I have script, which displaying random `.visible-content` div. I need that `display:none;` css function. I have no clue how to do this.. i am trying to do this f... maybe 5 days..

Comment: Se0ng11, i need to display only visible information, not all information :/

Comment: @Tauras, have you check the fiddle that I just updated?

Comment: Yes. Both answers are working. But now i have other question. How to hide information, which is not in the red background? I mean, that information has duplicate. In white space, and in the red space.

Comment: check this same fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b3deG/2/ again, although is best to open another question

Comment: I am checking it all the time :D. Well, you answered my main question. I will mark this as corrent. But i have second question for you. How to hide displayed information in white space, and show information only in red background?

Comment: @Tauras, is already answer in the fiddle, sorry just saw that the fiddle not updated, just add $(divs).hide(), http://jsfiddle.net/b3deG/10/

Answer (score 2):

I have forked and updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/Pjq97/) to check if that is what you wanted.

Whatever div you decide to show, `information-from-visible-content` will end up displaying that div.

Just added the following line to your fiddle:

```
$(".information-from-visible-content").html($(divs).html());
```

**Updated**

Once your `.information-from-visible-content` is updated, you can simple write the following line: `$(divs).hide()`. Updated Fiddle as well.

Comment: Both answers are working. But now i have other question. How to hide information, which is not in the red background? I mean, that information has duplicate. In white space, and in the red space.

Comment: Updated the answer to hide original visible div.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using jQuery traversing, using IDs or multiple classes.

```
<div class="visible-content content-1">
```

or

```
<div class="content" id="content-1">
```

In jQuery you can also traverse to the second instance of that class using next().

```
 $(div).next().append(content-1);
```

The API documentation on traversing will help finding the right selector [jQuery Traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: Like i said, i am not friendly with jquery. I have no clue how to write this code properly :/